# Making perfect rectangle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geometry, digitizing, extents

I want to be able to set the height and width of my rectangles, as well as the angles. I have been trying the Rectangles Ovals Digitizing plugin, but I can't seem to make it do anything (besides turn on, I did figure that part out). I'm not finding any tutorials on how to use this plugin. I'm fairly new to QGIS, so I may be missing something blatantly obvious!

I'm running Essen 2.14.

Comment: There is also the advanced digitize panel, used to be cad tools. See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141521/how-to-digitize-building-footprints-with-orthogonal-edges

Comment: You can try QAD plugin. It's cool!