# creating a single point from coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I need a simple way to enter or create a point from a set of coordinates on a geo referenced photomap in QGIS. The points are shipwreck coordinates that are then visually aligned with the reef features adjacent that we know are associated with the site. 
I am cleaning up a large set of coordinates from different sources and I need plot them and keep or reject them one at a time. After this process I can plot them all as a list. 
I am running 2.8.1

Comment: how about the quickWKT plugin?

Comment: One of these [answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34204/how-do-i-create-point-features-with-exact-coordinates) may be the solution to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to this:

- First you can put your coordinates into a simple CSV text file, then use the menu option: Layer->Add Layer-> Add Delimited Text Layer.
- There is a plugin xyToPoints where gives a graphical interface. Nice for entering one at a time.
- And the new plugin Spreadsheet Layers" allows you to import a list of coordinates directly from a spreadsheet table.