# Creating polygon using coordinates

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, polygon-creation

I am using QGIS 3.2 and I need to create an area to form a polygon shapefile using latitude and longitude, not using Python as I am just a beginner. How to do this?

Comment: Some of the CAD drawing tools should be what you're after: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34204/creating-point-features-with-exact-coordinates-in-qgis

Comment: There are various text file formats, that can be imported into QGis. Is importing a text file an option?

Comment: If You have Your latitude and longitude and perhaps other data in a table, you could use a plain .csv file and load it as text-layer: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file

Answer (score 10):

To give an example according to @geom recommendation. You must use the syntax to define polygons in [WKT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text),  here an example in CSV:

[image]

Finally use add delimited text data source:

[image]

With the following result:

[image]

To edit the question to provide an example of where I need to create a polygon via distances.

I need to create a polygon to represent a survey area. The survey area required is 3.58km x 3.0km. I have used the `v.buffer GRASS tool` and the `Buffer` tool. Which I select a certain point to buffer Around to create the survey area. However I cant find any input within these tools where I can enter such distances. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: perfect, thank you for providing an example. Would I follow the same formula if I wanted a polygon with specific dimensions rather than coordinates. e.g length in km.

Comment: Could @Bodhi provide some example, some data to provide what you require? I think it's best to do the coordinate calculations from the dimensions in the spreadsheet and then perform their representation in QGIS.

Comment: sure, Provided an example in the problem

Answer (score 5):

Use geojson. Just create a valid .geojson file with contents such as:

```
{"coordinates": [[[31, -5],
                  [32, -5],
                  [32, -4],
                  [31, -4],
                  [31, -5]]],
 "type": "Polygon"}
```

You can use a tool like [geojsonlint](https://geojsonlint.com/) to make sure the syntax is correct. Once you have a valid geojson, save it to a file, e.g my_polygon.geojson. Then, just drag and drop it to your "Layers" in QGIS. That's it.

[image]

In my opinion, this is much easier than the methods mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Note that geojson must follow the right-hand rule: https://mapster.me/right-hand-rule-geojson-fixer/

Comment: yes true. geojsonlint that I suggested checks that

Answer (score 3):

An addition to the answer above: I found it pretty complicated to write the WKT using the  boundary coordinates myself. If you have Postgres with Postgis extension (and possibly pgadmin) available (use the Docker version!), just execute the following:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_MakeEnvelope (
    12.147653576, 50.978794549, --lng-lat bounding 
    13.216635542, 51.684973715, --lng-lat box limits (Example)
    4326))
```

You will get back the eWKT formatted string:

```
SRID=4326;POLYGON((12.147653576 50.978794549,12.147653576 51.684973715,13.216635542 51.684973715,13.216635542 50.978794549,12.147653576 50.978794549))
```

This can be loaded using the answer above in QGIS with import CSV or using the **["QuickWKT" plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/visualising-wkt-geometry-string-in-qgis)**

For anyone who still wants to do this manually, here's the format for 2-coordinate bbox-polygon:

```sql
POLYGON((
left-lng bottom-lat,
left-lng top-lat,
right-lng top-lat,
right-lng bottom-lat,
left-lng bottom-lat))
```